# ¿Cómo puedo retroceder a la vista que estaba en vue js?

Tags: html, vue.js, router, routerlink

Estoy trabajando con VUE JS con sus rutas y necesito crear un botón que me retorne a la vista o ruta que estaba en vue js, por ejemplo el usuario está en la ruta "/profesores" y en algún menú se dirige a la ruta "/estudiantes", y que cuando de retroceder lo envíe de nuevo a "/profesores"; lo planteé poniendo:

```
<router-link :to="{name: '/home'}">Retroceder</router-link>
```

Pero eso solo es un botón en forma de constante ya que no devolverá al usuario a la ruta que estuvo, siempre lo enviará a "home" así antes haya estado en "profesores", quiero es que lo envíe a la ruta exacta que estuvo antes.

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#replace-current-location

Comment: Gracias, era lo que estaba necesitando, simplemente agregué al método que se ejecutaba al presionar el botón: "this.$router.go(-1);" e hiso lo que necesitaba. Éxitos!

Answer (score 1):

La solución está en poner ya sea en algún método del componente cuando éste se llama con:

```
$this.router.go(-1);
```

Lo cual hace que retroceda una vez, si se desea en vez de retroceder, avanzar; se haría de la misma manera pero con el valor positivo:

```
$this.router.go(1);
```

O bien en algún elemento en el template, se le hace lo mismo, solo que se quita el "$this":

```
<button @click="router.go(-1)">Retroceder</button>
```